# Regex matching CSS

Tags: python, css, regex

I've been trying do some regexp on css files to extract certain attributes but I'm having trouble matching from { to the first ; and so on .. here is what I've achieved so far:

Example css:

```
.pancake{height:200px;taste:delicious;}
```

I managed to write these 2 little pricks to work :

This one gets everything from the dot to the { :

```
(^\.[a-z]+)
```

This one gets everything between { } :

```
{.+}
```

I tried reading some regexp but can't understand how to match more than once occurrence or match until a certain character within another match ( sub-matching )

Comment: If you're trying to parse the CSS in any way (get certain attributes out of the text), I would suggest *not* using regex, but rather tokenizing the string.

Comment: That's another step !
Thank you for the reminder :)
But what I'm really trying to do now is selecting the correct data.

Comment: Do you only want to match the class pancake and its description ?

Comment: Yeah ! I wanted something like a key | value array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b(\w+):(\w+)(?=;)
```

Try this if you want to try regex.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/1

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b(\w+):(\w+)(?=;)')
test_str = u".pancake{height:200px;taste:delicious;}"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: That is precisely what I needed. I just altered 2 things but you gave me the help I needed.
  
`\b(\w+\:)(\w+\;)`

Answer (score 3):

As Jon said, parsing a CSS file using regular expressions is probably not a good idea. The CSS syntax presents many corner cases that you probably don't want to be handling by hand. I suggest you take a look at [tinycss](http://pythonhosted.org/tinycss/index.html), a nice CSS parsing library.

You can use it like this:

```
import tinycss as tcss

stylesheet = ".pancake{height:200px;taste:delicious;}"
parser = tcss.make_parser()
parsed = parser.parse_stylesheet(stylesheet)

for rule in parsed.rules:
    print "".join(t.as_css() for t in rule.selector)
    for declaration in rule.declarations:
        print "\t{0}: {1}".format(declaration.name, declaration.value.as_css())
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me on this didactic research. I acknowledge using a kind of library would definitively speed my final goal , but right now I am trying to learn it. Thanks nonetheless ! Your answer was helpful :)

Comment: I discovered this library yesterday and it's excellent. However, it depends on the quality of the CSS. For example, we are very inconsistent in how we define colours, so sometimes we use #eee, sometimes "whitesmoke" and sometimes #eeeeee. So I can use tinycss (actually I am at the moment) but I either have to standardise my CSS colour or I still need a regex to match a colour in a style string. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^:;\s]+)\s?:\s?([^;\s]+)(?=;)
```

will allow to parse attributes like: `background-color`, which @vks's answer did not.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'([^:;\s]+)\s?:\s?([^;\s]+)(?=;)')
re.findall(p, " background-color:#E6B8B7; text-align:center;")
```

Output:

```
[('background-color', '#E6B8B7'), ('text-align', 'center')]
```